# How fragment set the attribute "windowSoftInputMode"

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-manifest

I want to achieve the function which allow the `editview` comes above the `softinput` `keyboard` without the `edittext` twinkles(The Google plus's `edittext` has `somekind` twinkles).

Using `activity`,I can set `windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to achieve this but now I use fragment.So is there any way to also achieve this effect or to set the attribute of fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment using the view property of the parent's activity.
Then you just need to add windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" to corresponding activity.

Answer (score 0):

From fragments onCreateView() method you can do this:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```